# Viewcontroller Presenting issue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, uitabbarcontroller

I am facing one issue while Presenting `ViewController` with `Navigation.TabbarController` is `Rootview` of my application. I have used `BATabbarController`, but when I present `viewController` with Navigation , it presents with black background

```
let viewcontroller = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewIdentifire") as! ViewController
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewcontroller)

AppDelegate .shared().window?.rootViewController?.present(viewcontroller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**I am presenting controller form AppDelegates window**

Anyone have any idea why this happnes?

Thanks

Comment: Try changing this line `AppDelegate .shared().window?.rootViewController?.present(viewcontroller, animated: true, completion: nil)` to `AppDelegate .shared().window?.rootViewController?.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: present the navigation controller instead of ViewController

Comment: Try this: UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

Answer (score 1):

Please check in **Identity Inspector** are you set storyboard identifier with "viewIdentifire" ?

For better understanding please check attached screenshot. You will find this **Identity** in **Identity Inspector.**

[image]

Comment: It should be comment

Comment: @MikeAlter how i put screenshot in comment ? Please check i already attached screenshot.

Comment: I understand , You can not put screenshot in comment , But here screen shot is not really required .  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future,

Comment: @MikeAlter Yes, i know very well this answer will be visit by many SO visitors in future. But better understanding i attached screenshot. Because it may happen some time in hurry we can't find appropriate place, when we have to make changes as per SO answer. Now, if you don't have no any issue regarding this, then only you can remove downvote. Otherwise i have no any issue for the same. Thank you. :)

Comment: I can't  removing My Down Vote  system not allow to do so, you better delete your answer . it is really not an answer of the question Thank you

Comment: @MikeAlter, If above one is not the correct answer, then please put your answer. I will happy making upvote to your answer.

Comment: You don't need to loose your cool bro, I am not blaming you , My concern was only that it should be comment not much, Thank you